# understanding what Serializers do and how they do and also where can i log my request in case of class based views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this code which for my views

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Question.objects.all()
    lookup_field="slug"
    serializer_class=QuestionSerializer
    permission_classes=[IsAuthorOrReadOnly,IsAuthenticated]
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print("user is", self.request.user)
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

and this code for serializers

```
   class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
   created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
   answers_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   user_has_answered = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   print("author in serializer", author)
   class Meta:
       model = Question
       exclude = ["updated_at"]

   def get_created_at(self, instance):
       return instance.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

   def get_answers_count(self, instance):
       return instance.answers.count()

   def get_user_has_answered(self, instance):
       request = self.context.get("request")
       return instance.answers.filter(author=request.user).exists()
```

Then i have this code for models

```
    class Question(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="questions")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.content)

        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What i basically fail to do is to log the request .In case of function based i could easily log the request and see as what data is coming .However in case of class based views i fail to do this .
Also , I don't understand as where data is being saved in case of post request .I don't  see ny save etc .
Please enlighten as how this works fine ?

Comment: `self.request` will be the WSGI request coming into your view

Answer (score 0):

To log a request data you can override a dispatch method:

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    # log the request here
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Also you may consider using something more "broad" like setting your own [midlleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#middleware).

As for create - magic happens in viewset create method. You can override it as well:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something unusual here
```

Comment: u mean to say  when it is not written it still  does . the save .How do people even debug such code ?

Comment: @horrible_nerd well, yes, that the advantage of inheritance which you actually did when defined `viewsets.ModelViewSet` as a parent class for your own.

Answer (score 0):

instead of overriding the dispatch, better solution you can write the middleware which log the request data.

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/

lass SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```